# Does "go about choosing" mean "*begin* choosing" here?

Tags: meaning

This video (https://youtu.be/K69jbdvMPMc?t=39) is saying

> What we're going to do in this video is talk about how to *go about* choosing
>   these two parameter values theta 0 and theta 1.

What does "go about" here mean?

oxford dictionaries (http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/go) gives this meaning

> begin or carry on work at (an activity); busy oneself with.
>
> change to an opposite tack.

So, does that part mean "how to *begin* choosing"?

Comment: Yes it is, *“Begin or carry on work at (an activity); busy oneself with.”*  To paraphrase, he is saying, “In this video we are going to learn how to *carry out the activity of* choosing...”  Other examples: *“When the guests check out, they go about stripping the beds and cleaning the rooms.”  and “Do you know how to go about fixing a dripping tap?”*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the meanings of "go about", according to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary,, is "to start working on something"

> I'm not going about the job in the right way.
>   How should I go about finding the job?

Comment: To go about something can mean to choose an approach to, or method of, doing something.

Comment: I don't think ***to go about*** has any particular implications for ***beginning*** something. If I say ***He's going about his business as usual***, there's no suggestion of ***starting*** anything. It's just that in typical usages such as ***I don't know how to go about fixing it***, the context itself implies I don't know how to ***start** fixing it.*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: I think _go about one's business_ is a specific idiom: the only noun I can think of that your can replace _business_ with without getting the meaning of "choosing an approach" _life_.  A search on iWeb for "go about (noun)" gives me 1080 "go about things", all or most of which have the idea of an approach. "Go about life" gets 172, and "go about business" 100, and these are mostly not denoting an approach to something. But most the rest of the 3617 results have the meaning of "an approach or method of doing something".

Comment: @ColinFine: I think the word ***approach*** there just irrelevantly skews things. To my mind *He's going about it the wrong way* essentially means he's ***doing it*** the wrong way, regardless of how long ago he started. If you don't buy into that perspective, it's difficult to explain why "continuous" [***...been going** about it the wrong way*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22been+going+about+it+the+wrong+way%22) occurs so often in print.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: I don't think we're disagreeing, just interpreting the terms differently. I agree that there is nothing specifically about starting; but I think that ("business" and "life" aside) it has to do with the **way** you are doing or seeing a thing (whether or not the word "way" comes into it), not just that you are carrying it on. That is what I intend by "approach", not the initial stage.

Comment: @ColinFine:oic, yes. Thinking about it some more, it seems to me that ***going about*** something is often a kind of "emphatic" alternative to actually ***doing*** it. So *You're going about it wrong* is more like *You're doing it **all** wrong*. Which imho makes *You're going about it **all** wrong* an even *more* emphatic form (the way you're doing it is wrong *from start to finish / in all ways / from every angle*)